# SVG size not reducing

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am inserting an SVG with a helper text. so, I want to reduce the size of the SVG. How to do that?

// App.js

```js
import { ReactComponent as UserIcon } from "./user.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <UserIcon />
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

// user.svg

```js
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M24 44q-6.9-1.6-11.45-7.825Q8 29.95 8 21.9V9.95l16-6 16 6v13.5q-.7-.35-1.5-.625T37 22.45v-10.4l-13-4.8-13 4.8v9.85q0 3.8 1.225 7t3.125 5.625q1.9 2.425 4.2 4.025 2.3 1.6 4.45 2.3.3.6.9 1.35.6.75 1 1.15-.45.25-.95.375-.5.125-.95.275Zm10.55-9.5q1.3 0 2.2-.95.9-.95.9-2.25t-.9-2.2q-.9-.9-2.2-.9-1.3 0-2.25.9t-.95 2.2q0 1.3.95 2.25t2.25.95Zm-.05 6.25q1.65 0 3-.7t2.3-2q-1.3-.7-2.6-1.05-1.3-.35-2.7-.35-1.4 0-2.725.35-1.325.35-2.575 1.05.95 1.3 2.275 2t3.025.7Zm.15 3.25q-3.9 0-6.65-2.775-2.75-2.775-2.75-6.575 0-3.9 2.75-6.675t6.65-2.775q3.85 0 6.625 2.775t2.775 6.675q0 3.8-2.775 6.575Q38.5 44 34.65 44ZM24 24.05Z"/></svg>
```

If I change "height" and "width", the SVG is cut off, instead of reduced in size.

one solution that worked for me is, I kept 'id' to `<path>` and used `transform: scale(0.5)`, but I don't want to use 'id'. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: you can transform the icon, like this : `<UserIcon style={{ transform: "scale(0.5)" }} />`

Comment: Instead of `height="48" width="48"` use `viewBox="0 0 48 48"` and use the width you need for example `width="24"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the css [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) function.

> The scale() CSS function defines a transformation that resizes an
> element on the 2D plane. Because the amount of scaling is defined by a
> vector, it can resize the horizontal and vertical dimensions at
> different scales. Its result is a  data type.

The `scale()` function is specified with either one or two values, which represent the amount of scaling to be applied in each direction.

**Usage:**

`scale(sx)`

`scale(sx, sy)`

**Function Values:**

***sx***:
A `number` or `percentage` representing the abscissa of the scaling vector.

***sy***:
A `number` or `percentage` representing the ordinate of the scaling vector. If not defined, its default value is sx, resulting in a uniform scaling that preserves the element's aspect ratio.

For `scale(sx, sy)` see following example using your code:

***App.js***

```
import "./styles.css";

import { ReactComponent as UserIcon } from "./user.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <UserIcon style={{ transform: "scale(0.25, 0.25)" }} />
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***user.svg***

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48"><path d="M24 44q-6.9-1.6-11.45-7.825Q8 29.95 8 21.9V9.95l16-6 16 6v13.5q-.7-.35-1.5-.625T37 22.45v-10.4l-13-4.8-13 4.8v9.85q0 3.8 1.225 7t3.125 5.625q1.9 2.425 4.2 4.025 2.3 1.6 4.45 2.3.3.6.9 1.35.6.75 1 1.15-.45.25-.95.375-.5.125-.95.275Zm10.55-9.5q1.3 0 2.2-.95.9-.95.9-2.25t-.9-2.2q-.9-.9-2.2-.9-1.3 0-2.25.9t-.95 2.2q0 1.3.95 2.25t2.25.95Zm-.05 6.25q1.65 0 3-.7t2.3-2q-1.3-.7-2.6-1.05-1.3-.35-2.7-.35-1.4 0-2.725.35-1.325.35-2.575 1.05.95 1.3 2.275 2t3.025.7Zm.15 3.25q-3.9 0-6.65-2.775-2.75-2.775-2.75-6.575 0-3.9 2.75-6.675t6.65-2.775q3.85 0 6.625 2.775t2.775 6.675q0 3.8-2.775 6.575Q38.5 44 34.65 44ZM24 24.05Z"/></svg>
```

See [this Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-joana-uovuhd) for a live demo.